# How do I rename the child of a clone in three.js? (renaming children / child objects)

Tags: javascript, three.js, clone, parent-child, rename

I have created a 3D model made from various parts:
`ParentObject-001.name = 'ParentObject-001';`
`ChildObjectA-001.name = 'ChildObjectA-001';`
`ChildObjectB-001.name = 'ChildObjectB-001';`

and then:
`ParentObject-001.add(ChildObject-001A, ChildObject-001B);`
This works, all parts rotate and change position when the parent moves.

So When I:
`ParentObject-002=ParentObject.clone();`
a perfect copy is made, but:

`ParentObject-002.name = 'ParentObject-001'`
This was expected, so...

`ParentObject-002.name='ParentObject-002';`
fixes it.

However, the child of ParentObject-002`
named ChildObjectA-001 needs to be changed.

How can this be done?

I have tried addressing the object to move it by:
`ParentObject-002.ChildObjectA-001`
and:
`ParentObject-002[0]`
Neither of them work, both returned 'undefined'

I'm still kind of new to this...
Did I overlook something more simple?

Answer (score 1):

I got it! Each and every Parent element/object
has an array automatically created for it called .children.

MyObject.children[0]  is the first entry.

Each one gives access to the .name property.

if I had an array of shoes:

`shoeNo[k][l].children[1].name='whatIWannaCallIt';`
lets my rename the second child of a shoe at row k, column l. etc.